# Which model should k-fold cross validation return?

Tags: machine-learning

I have read a bit about k-fold cross validation. I know that it measures each model's performance as a number and returns the average. But I still don't know, which of the k models is returned as a result. Or is a model returned at all? Or is the result the model of all data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-validation is used to measure the model performance. You can use any of the k models it produced as your model to launch. But usually in my experience, we actually do NOT use any of them.

Once we used cross validation to evaluate the model performance and finalized the hyper-parameters, we use ALL the data available to train another model. That one is used as the launch candidate.